# Modal Segue Form Sheet Blurred Background

Tags: ios, swift3, segue, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal segue *(with the Form Sheet presentation)* which I call whenever a `tableViewCell` is selected. I have the segue set up in the storyboard, but if needed, I can set it up programaticly. I want the background of the modal view to be a `Visual Effect View with Blur` instead of the translucent black color. How can I do this? Thanks for the help! I'm using Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by implementing two protocols - for your `Animator`, `<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>` and for `TransitioningDelegate`, `<UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>`.

In `Animator`, you'll need to override method `animateTransition` and create there `UIVisualEffectView`, which you'll add onto a `transitionContext.containerView`

```
class Animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning
{
    func blurEffectView(_ transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIVisualEffectView
    {
        let container = transitionContext.containerView;
        var effectView = objc_getAssociatedObject(container, &BlurEffectViewKey) as? UIVisualEffectView;
        if effectView == nil
        {
            let effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)

            effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: effect);
            objc_setAssociatedObject(container, &BlurEffectViewKey, effectView!, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
            container.addSubview(effectView!);
            effectView!.frame = container.bounds;

        }
        return effectView!;
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)
    {
        ...

        let blurView = self.blurEffectView(transitionContext);

        if (presenting)
        {
            blurView.contentView.addSubview(toController.view);
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, you setup and present your modal controller:

```
presentedViewController.transitioningDelegate = myTransitioningDelegate
presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(presentedViewController, animated:false, completion:nil)
```

For more detailed information, please refer to WWDC'13 session "[Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/218xdx4xj2umojkv3e8dbk6i/218/218.pdf?dl=1)"